# MVC AntiForgeryToken cookie missing in browser before login.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, csrf, antiforgerytoken

Application is accessed under https:// url.

In MVC application we have added @@Html.AntiForgeryToken() on cshtml razor engine and ValidateAntiForgeryToken on controller.

It all worked fine for after login pages, but with login page it goes to application error as there was no cookie seen on browser before logging into the system.

Went through several forums, articles and even added the following piece of code in global.asax.

```
  AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName = "CSRF";
  AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks = true;
  //AntiForgeryConfig.RequireSsl = true; -- only for https.
```

Even wrote a simple SetCookie in get method of login page, that cookie doesn't show up on browser. What could be the problem.

Why i was able to see the below in cshtml but controller doesn't accept the post with antiforgeryvalidation before login. 
    .

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If i comment out the ValidateAntiForgeryToken from AccountController post method I'm all good but thats not serving the purpose. We want all post to be validated.